# How to use .pop and .append to do FIFO (instead of LIFO) while processing a list?

Tags: python

I'm learning python using the Python Crash Course book, doing exercises on filling lists with user input.  I completed this exercise below, but wanted to learn how to change the code so that the lists' order matches.

I read about Python lists as FIFO, LIFO queues using deque, but don't understand how to use those data structures yet.

```
sandwich_orders = ['cheese', 'ham', 'turkey', 'pb&j', 'chicken salad']

finished_sandwiches = []

for sandwich in sandwich_orders:
    print("I received your " + sandwich + " sandwich order.")

while sandwich_orders:
    current_sandwich = sandwich_orders.pop()
    print("Making " + current_sandwich.title() + " sandwich.")
    finished_sandwiches.append(current_sandwich)

print("\nThe following sandwiches have been made:")
for sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
    print(sandwich.title())
```

Printing the current_sandwich list is in reverse order from the sandwich_orders list.  I'd like current_sandwich to print in the same order as the sandwich_orders list.

Comment: Pop from the correct side...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.insert` with position `0` instead of `list.append`:

```
while sandwich_orders:
    current_sandwich = sandwich_orders.pop()
    print("Making " + current_sandwich.title() + " sandwich.")
    finished_sandwiches.insert(0, current_sandwich)
```

You can also `list.pop` from position `0` and use `list.append`:

```
while sandwich_orders:
    current_sandwich = sandwich_orders.pop(0)
    print("Making " + current_sandwich.title() + " sandwich.")
    finished_sandwiches.append(current_sandwich)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `deque` API is similar to the `list` API. You can still use `append` to add new elements. You'll just use `popleft` instead of `pop` to remove the leftmost element.

```
from collections import deque

sandwich_orders = deque(['cheese', 'ham', 'turkey', 'pb&j', 'chicken salad'])

finished_sandwiches = deque()

for sandwich in sandwich_orders:
    print("I received your " + sandwich + " sandwich order.")

while sandwich_orders:
    current_sandwich = sandwich_orders.popleft()
    print("Making " + current_sandwich.title() + " sandwich.")
    finished_sandwiches.append(current_sandwich)

print("\nThe following sandwiches have been made:")
for sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
    print(sandwich.title())
```